# mysql command works in terminal but not in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I have the strangest problem. The following bash script doesn't execute properly. But when the same commands are entered one by one on the terminal, they work

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""  
read -s -p "Enter DB Password : " dbpass  
echo ""  
echo ""  
docker run --name mariadb -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$dbpass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -d mariadb:10.2.14  
sleep 5  
docker exec -i mariadb mysql -u root -p$dbpass < mysql.sql
```

I get the following error when I run the bash script :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: What does `echo $dbpass` tell you?  I'll bet it's either not being set, or is not the value you think it is.

Comment: May be your console SHELL is not bash. Try `echo $SHELL"`.